# Android - json-smart deserialization issue

Tags: android, json

I have a strange problem in my Android code when I try to pass json-smart `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` as a serializable data as Intent serializable extra. [Json-smart](http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/) is very fast and lean JSON parser implementation, I highly recommend it. `JSONObject` extends `HashMap<String, Object>` and `JSONArray` extends `ArrayList<Object>` with very little overhead. Nether of these objects override `Object#write` or `Object#read`

Here's the problem:

If I use these objects in say `Fragment#onSaveInstanceState(String, JSONObject)` everything works just fine. If I serialize/deserialize these objects in plain Java sample project, again it works as intended. However if I use `Intent#putExtra(String, JSONObject)` and then try to get my JSONObject by doing

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) intent.getSerializableExtra("JSON");
```

I will get `ClassCastException` because what is returned by the method is a plain `HashMap` (and in case of JSONArray it's ArrayList). Moreover if I look inside the map/array the content is completely stripped of any references to JSONObject/JSONArray and replaced with HashMaps/ArrayLists

I [filed the ticket](http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/issues/detail?id=18) and provided example project but unfortunately author closed it without resolution, so I'm simply trying to get to the bottom of it. If you go to the ticket it has simple project attached.

Is there a way out of this? For now I have to convert JSONObject or JSONArray to String and reparse it back to the object such as in:

```
JSONArray feeds = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(intent.getStringExtra(RAW_FEED));
```

Comment: fyi, `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getSerializableExtra("JSON"))` should work just dandy.

Comment: @Jens this does not work (at least fully). Yes - you will get outer JSONObject but all internal structure will be plain HashMaps and ArrayLists. I just verified this by modifying and executing test project that is included with the ticket

Comment: Yep.  JSON Object can be constructed from HashMap, and actually is a HashMap.

Comment: Just a question,  is JSONSmart available on both sides in the same version? This is most common soource of [de]serialization mishaps

Comment: Question clearly outlines HashMap/ArrayList nature of objects. What do you mean by "both sides"? Library is supplied as jar. There's small test project attached to the ticket, you welcome to try any combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement android.os.Parcelable:

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html
```

Basically, you put a little extra code into your object to explain how to serialize and deserialize it.  That's why it's losing your class information, it doesn't know how to serialize it correctly.  If I were you I would pass a value object through your intent verses a JSON object simply because know you know exactly what type of object you are passing.  You retrieve your Parcelable this way:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable(key);
```

I know it probably seems like a little extra code but I actually think this is a pretty clean way to share data between activities.  You are passing a strong type, you specify how to deflate/inflate it, and your activities don't really have to have any working knowledge of each other.

In your value object you just fill in the blanks like this:

```
/** Parcelable implementation: deserialize object
 * @param in Parcel object containing the data for this object
 * @return a Person object  */
public Person( Parcel in ) {
    String[] data = new String[2];
    in.readStringArray(data);
    this.firstName = data[0];
    this.lastName = data[1];
}

/** Parcelable implementation code */
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

/** Parcelable implementation: Serialize object to be passed between activities via Intent
 * @param dest The parcel to transport the object
 * @param flags refer to Parcelable api
 * @return nothing */
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray( new String[] {
            this.firstName,
            this.lastName,      
    });
}
```

Hope this helps, might be little more code than what you were looking for but it's a real clean solution because when the target activity gets the object, you don't have to worry about deserializing which means cleaner code in your activity.  Fat model, clean views :)

Comment: I'm trying not to augment JSON objects but use "as is". I'm kind of puzzled with deserialization issue and want to understand why Android in this particular case strips out object type

Comment: When you implement Parcelable, you are telling Android how to serialize and deserialize your object without losing any info, such as the type.  That's where your problem lies, when you pass JSONObject, which is a class just like my Person example, Android does not know how to handle it. If you want a generic way to pass a JSON object, try creating a value object that has one property of type JSONObject for the payload.  Implement Parcelable on that value object.  That will give you a transport object to send your JSON objects through.  More of a design suggestion but it should work :)

Comment: I'm not sure that doing it this way will be more efficient than converting/parsing plain String

Comment: Fair enough, you could simply pass it as a raw string.  Your question was, why it was losing the class type when you passed it through the intent.  The answer is, complex types are meant to be passed as Parcelabe objects.  I don't think anyone would dispute that fact.  Sorry if you don't like that answer, just trying to help and maybe clarify exactly why that is the preferred method.  Best of luck to ya :)

Comment: It also means that I would have to write Parcel routines which probably will end up being same String serialization but will require complex parsing logic (or converting the whole thing into String). So I think I hit a dead end here and since no easy answer is provided I will have to use String serialization just as I'm doing now. Thanks for marking all these valuable points, I'm not sure your answer qualifies for full bounty but I'll uptick it for sure

Comment: On the front page of the json-smart page you listed, it very clearly states that version 1.x and 2.x serialize/deserialize to maps.  Intent#putExtra(String, JSONObject) calls serialize per android docs... which per the site would result in a map.  The only way to get around that is to call the same Intent#putExtra(String, JSONObject) and pass a Parcelable in which will retain your class info.  That is the exact answer to your question, "why am I losing the class type and getting a map".  Now you may not like the solution but I clearly answered your question.  :P

Comment: That statement on front page refers to ability to serialize/deserialize beans to/from JSON not to the fact that in Android the type is somehow degraded to the HashMap. I think the reason the type is lost in Android is that object wrapper (JSONObject) does not override write/readObject and somehow Android loses the type while deserializing. So my question to clarify is why, since serialization/deserialization happily works in plain Java project or even in Android when you serialize/deserialize to file. Perhaps for performance sake I can use Application pseudo-singleton?

Comment: I think I explained pretty clearly why you are getting a map when you pass the class JSONObject through the putExtra method of an intent.  If you want to step outside of that and talk design I would probably bring up the fact that having an activity rely on some dynamic JSON object is bad design.  I would parse the JSON into a value object and pass it through as a parcelable.  That's just me though, I have no idea what business rules you have in place that drive your app.  Good luck though, I'm sure others will find this topic very useful and in the end that's why we are here :)

Comment: I'll give you a bounty just because you carry on the conversation :) My problem is that parsing the String degrades the performance and eats memory and I hate to do unnecessary work, I don't think going Parcel route saves me anything so I'll look at the Application object which unfortunately prone to memory leaking

Comment: I don't think you would notice a performance hit unless you are writing a game.  On another note, Ive put a singleton model in my Application object and it worked pretty well.  That's not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 1):

As a JSON-Object implicitly is a String, why so don't simply pass it as String?

```
// save the json string
JSONObject json = ...
intent.putExtra("json", json.toString());


// Let's read it in in the next activity
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtra("json"));
```

Comment: That's what I do. But this requires re-parsing String to object and is surprisingly expensive

Comment: And also see my answer (to my own question)

Answer (score 0):

If you reading this and wondering which solution I finally implemented I realized that I can happily use stripped-down version of Map/List based object since it retains the structure and all the keys. No need to monkey with Parcelable